# Tapkey Management API: Endpoint for checking downtime?

Tags: tapkey

Is there a way to check for scheduled downtime of the Tapkey Management API?
Is there a way to check the current status of the Tapkey Management API (up and running / down)?

Answer (score 1):

The Tapkey Management API is designed for zero downtime, so there is no need for an endpoint announcing scheduled downtimes. If you want to check, whether the service is up and running you may query `https://my.tapkey.com/version` and see whether you get a successful response. You may also approach Tapkey support and ask for being added to a mailing list announcing system changes.